# AngularJS: Refactoring a confirmation modal directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need some advice on refactoring a modal directive I have. I am just getting started with directives, so any other approach to my problem is welcome.

My program needs a confirmation modal, where we can confirm or cancel the desired action. It will appear in many places and needs to be able to have a programmable button. Cancel is consistent in that it will only hide the modal, the confirmation button needs to perform whatever action required.

I am currently using `$rootScope` to show / hide / configure the modal. Is this a bad idea? Please tell me.

This is what I am working with right now (roughly, as I have cut out a lot of the other unnecessary code):

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MenuCtrl">

        <confirmmodal ng-show="$root.confirmModal.isVisible"></confirmmodal>

        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-view></div>

        <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
</html>
```

So my modal sits atop the `ng-view` and can be called from anywhere. It is inside a pseudo global controller, called `MenuCtrl`.

Here is the modal directive code:

**directives.js**

```
/* Confirm Modal */
.directive('confirmmodal', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'view/templates/modal-confirm.tpl.html'
    };
}])
```

It serves as a template for the following code:

**modal-confirm.tpl.html**

```
<!-- Confirm Modal Template -->
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content extended">
        <span>{{$root.confirmModal.content}}</span>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$root.confirmModal.secondary.action()">{{$root.confirmModal.secondary.content}}</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$root.confirmModal.primary.action()">{{$root.confirmModal.primary.content}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I set a bunch of defaults in the `app.run` function:

**app.js**

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    _.extend($rootScope, {
        confirmModal: {
            isVisible: false,
            content: '',
            primary: {
                action: function() {
                    console.log('hello world');
                },
                content: 'Submit'
            },
            secondary: {
                action: function() {
                    $rootScope.confirmModal.isVisible = false;
                },
                content: 'Cancel'
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

So I've also coded a modal trigger directive, the idea being that I can create different triggers that perform different actions with the modal.

**directives.js**

```
/* Resolve Event */
.directive('resolveevent', ['RequestService', '$location', function (RequestService, $location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            eventtype: '@',
            eventid: '@',
            index: '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.remove = function(id) {
                // remove the event from the events array
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.events.splice(id, 1);
            },

            $scope.config = function(config) {
                _.extend($scope.$root.confirmModal, config);
            },

            $scope.isVisible = function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.$root.confirmModal.isVisible = true;
                });
            }
        }],
        link: function( $scope, element, attrs ) {
            var config = {
                content: 'Are you sure you wish to resolve this event?',
                primary: {
                    action: function() {
                        var config = {
                            url: '/Events/' + $scope.eventid,
                            method: 'PUT',
                            data: {
                                event_status: 'resolved'
                            },
                            cache: false
                        }

                        /* Update event with resolved status */
                        RequestService.makeApiRequest(config).success(function(response) {
                            $scope.$root.confirmModal.isVisible = false;
                            $scope.remove($scope.index);
                        });
                    },
                    content: 'Resolve Event'
                }
            }

            element.on('click', function() {
                if (!$scope.$root.confirmModal.isVisible) {
                    $scope.config(config);
                    $scope.isVisible();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

And then I use a button on the view where my `ng-repeat` is found which is able to trigger the modal:

**eventlist.html**

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events">

    <p>Event: {{ event.number }}</p>
    <p>Group: {{ event.group_name }}</p>
    <p>Record Date: {{ event.event_date | moment: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A' }}</p>

    <button resolveevent index="{{$index}}" eventid="{{ event.number }}" class="btn btn-default">Resolve</button>
</li>
```

This is what I've got, and it is working, however it seems like overkill, inefficient, and a nightmare to maintain. Can anyone chime in on a way to improve this? I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using the angular-ui-bootstrap module?  It has a modal window available and would require less code of your own. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the bootstrap-ui project : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

If you're using Bootstrap 3, be careful about the templates, and use the version without them. You can download bootstrap3 compliant templates here : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/bootstrap3_bis2_modalPatch

Comment: I ended up using the modal code from the bootstrap project and modifying it to my requirements, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple directive to confirm:

```
/**
 * A generic confirmation for risky actions.
 * Usage: Add attributes: ng-really-message="Really?" ng-really-click="takeAction()" function
 */
angular.module('app').directive('ngReallyClick', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                var message = attrs.ngReallyMessage;
                if (message && confirm(message)) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.ngReallyClick);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Good answer @EpokK, you are not a noob !

Answer (score 0):

My method might not be according to best practises, but I usually end up creating dedicated service that both has access to modal's scope and manipulates dom. Think of it as self injecting directive.

Here's the modal's container html (uses bootstrap's styling):

```
<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" ng-style="{width: width}">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button ng-repeat="(name, callback) in buttons" type="button" ng-click="callback()">{{name}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then there's pseudo code of the DialogService:

```
.service('DialogService', function($compile, $http, $rootScope) {
  this.open = function(options) {
     //options contain various properties
     //e.g. title, width, template or templateUrl, button map with callbacks
     loadModalContainer()
     .then(loadModalBody)
     .then(init);

     function init() {
       modal = $('body').append(containerHtml).find('.modal');
       modal.append(bodyHtml);
       scope = (options.scope || $rootScope).$new();
       if (options.controller) $controller(options.controller, {$scope: scope});
       $compile(modal)(scope);
       listenForEscKey();
     }
     function close() {
       //clean up event listeners
       //
       if (options.onClose) options.onClose();
       scope.$destroy();
       $('body').find('.modal,.modal-backdrop').remove();
     }
  }
});
```

Of course, because of the async nature of the service, you have to implement some auto-close logic if second modal pops-up. From there is really easy, you can define concrete dialogs as separate services to abstract away the details:

```
 .service('TermsModal', function(DialogService) {
    this.open = function(acceptCallback, declineCallback, scope) {
       DialogService.open({
         templateUrl: '',
         width: '',
         buttons: {
           accept: acceptCallback,
           decline: declineCallback
         }, 
         scope: scope
       });
    }
 })
```

Then from any controller you can open modal with an one-liner: `TermsModal.open(acceptCallback, declineCallback, $scope)`

There are several issues. First of all, it would be great to use transclusion, since now modal's child scope is littered with `title, buttons, width` properties.

Another thing is that I pass around modal body's width, but that's just my laziness (I cannot style bootstraps modal body width properly since it's hardcoded).

Also, I pass around local scopes from controllers because very often modal's body content is in one or another way related to the controller that invokes the modal. If, say, we have ItemController with `item` as scope property and we have an edit button to edit item's value in a modal, the child scope has to know about the model it's dealing with. So either it's passing around scope or passing needed values directly in options. I prefer scope because that gives more flexibility and with child scope intialization it is really hard to mess up orginal model.

All in all, the power and flexibility this set-up gives justifies the fact that service is messing a bit with the DOM. Your rootScope becomes free of global state (the service manages its own state without giving details to the outside world) and your main template is free of modal partials/directives/whatever that may or may not be used.

Comment: Your answer was useful for me! I made this: https://gist.github.com/g-alonso/8278443

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small confirmation directive which, opens a modal and executes the code you want, if the modal is confirmed:

**app.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
 nait-confirm-click
 confirm="Do you really want to remove this record?"
 confirm-if="user.disabled == true"
 do="remove(user)">
    Remove
</button>
```

**script.js**

```
angular
    .module('xyz', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .directive('naitConfirmClick', function($modal, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                if (!attrs.do) {
                    return;
                }

                // register the confirmation event
                var confirmButtonText = attrs.confirmButtonText ? attrs.confirmButtonText : 'OK';
                var cancelButtonText = attrs.cancelButtonText ? attrs.cancelButtonText : 'Cancel';
                element.click(function() {
                    // action that should be executed if user confirms
                    var doThis = $parse(attrs.do);

                    // condition for confirmation
                    if (attrs.confirmIf) {
                        var confirmationCondition = $parse(attrs.confirmIf);
                        if (!confirmationCondition(scope)) {
                            // if no confirmation is needed, we can execute the action and leave
                            doThis(scope);
                            scope.$apply();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    $modal
                        .open({
                            template: '<div class="modal-body">' + attrs.confirm + '</div>'
                                + '<div class="modal-footer">'
                                +     '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-naitsirch-confirm pull-right" ng-click="$close(\'ok\')">' + confirmButtonText + '</button>'
                                +     '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-naitsirch-cancel pull-right" ng-click="$dismiss(\'cancel\')">' + cancelButtonText + '</button>'
                                + '</div>'
                        })
                        .result.then(function() {
                            doThis(scope);
                            scope.$apply()
                        })
                    ;
                });
            }
        };
    })
;
```

Now, if you click on the button with the *nait-confirm-click* it opens a modal with two buttons and the text you have passed by the *confirm* attribute. If you click the cancel button, nothing will happen. If you confirm by clicking *"OK"*, the expression, which you have passed by the *do* attribute, will be executed.

If you pass an expression in the optional *confirm-if* attribute, the modal will only be opened if the expression is true. If the expression is false, the action will be executed without asking.

I hope this snippet will help someone ;)